# Create Customizable Calender

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I Need a calendar option and need to mark holidays and description for holidays \days on it. How can i create a calendar with customize option? Is it possible using jquery?

Comment: take a look on full calendar library. I used it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTMl

```
    <div id="calEventDialog">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
        <label for="eventTitle">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="eventTitle" id="eventTitle" /><br>
        <label for="eventStart">Start Date</label>
        <input type="text" name="eventStart" id="eventStart" /><br>
        <label for="eventEnd">End Date</label>
        <input type="text" name="eventEnd" id="eventEnd" /><br>
        <input type="radio" id="allday" name="allday" value="1">
        Half Day
        <input type="radio" id="allday" name="allday" value="2">
        All Day
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<div style="border:solid 2px red;">
        <div id='myCalendar'></div>
</div>
```

and JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dates = $("#eventStart, #eventEnd").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            var option = this.id == "eventStart" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
            dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
        }
    });

    $myCalendar = $('#myCalendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },
        theme: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        height: 500,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            $('#eventStart').datepicker("setDate", new Date(start));
            $('#eventEnd').datepicker("setDate", new Date(end));
            $('#calEventDialog').dialog('open');
        },
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#eventStart').datepicker("setDate", new Date(calEvent.start));
            $('#eventEnd').datepicker("setDate", new Date(calEvent.end));
            $('#calEventDialog #eventTitle').val(calEvent.title);
            $('#calEventDialog #allday').val([calEvent.className == "gbcs-halfday-event" ? "1" : "2"]).prop('checked', true);
            $("#calEventDialog").dialog("option", "buttons", [
                {
                text: "Save",
                click: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }},
            {
                text: "Delete",
                click: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }},
            {
                text: "Cancel",
                click: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }}
            ]);
            $("#calEventDialog").dialog("option", "title", "Edit Event");
            $('#calEventDialog').dialog('open');
        },
        editable: true
    });

    var title = $('#eventTitle');
    var start = $('#eventStart');
    var end = $('#eventEnd');
    var eventClass, color;
    $('#calEventDialog').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Add Event',
        width: 400,
        buttons: {
            Save: function() {
                if ($('input:radio[name=allday]:checked').val() == "1") {
                    eventClass = "gbcs-halfday-event";
                    color = "#9E6320";
                    end.val(start.val());
                }
                else {
                    eventClass = "gbcs-allday-event";
                    color = "#875DA8";
                }
                if (title.val() !== '') {
                    $myCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                        title: title.val(),
                        start: start.val(),
                        end: end.val(),
                        allDay: true,
                        className: eventClass,
                        color: color
                    }, true // make the event "stick"
                    );
                }
                $myCalendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

for Reference http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/xgSTr/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use Zabuto Calendar plugin . Please find its Description on below link http://zabuto.com/dev/calendar/examples/index.html

include below js files

```
<!-- js start -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="js/zabuto_calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/holiday.json"></script>

<!-- js end -->
```

include below css files

```
<!-- css start -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/zabuto_calendar.min.css">
<!-- css end -->
```

include below script which pass event data in json format and call plugin

```
  <script>
    var date=[];
    var event=[];
    var e=[];
     $(document).ready(function() {

     holidayList();
                    $(".my-calendar").zabuto_calendar({
                        cell_border : true,
                        today : true,
                        data : e,


    });
});

     function holidayList(obj){
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    date[key]=changeFormat(val.holidayDate);
    event[key]=val.description;
    //alert(DT[key]);
     e[key] = {"date": date[key],"badge": false,"title": event[key]};

    var e1 = $('<label class="col-offset-2">'+val.holidayDate+' :   '+val.description+'</label><br>');
                        $('#Holiday').append(e1); 


                        });

    </script>
```

and display calendar using below html code

```
<!-- main content start -->
<div class="holidayCalender">
    <div class="my-calendar">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="Holiday" class="col-sm-6 " >
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- main content ends -->
```

Comment: It is not working for me. Getting error message: fullcalendar.min.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined

Comment: I was not able find calendar.js and holidayCal.js files.

Comment: you need to download plugin of calendar.js  and zabuto calendar.js which I have included in js file section and in this case no need to include holidayCal.js because script is included inside page only. and holiday.json file contain json data which will be in this format data=[{
 "companyCD": "002",
 "holidayDate": "26-01-2016",
 "description": "Republic Day",
 "fullDay": "Y",
 "HolidayType" : "Public Holiday"
 
}, {
 "companyCD": "002",
 "holidayDate": "24-03-2016",
 "description": "Holi",
 "fullDay": "Y",
 "HolidayType" : "Public Holiday"
}]

Comment: Is it same as 'fullcalendar.js'? When i try to download calendar.js i am  only getting fullcalendar.js.

Comment: i have just tried an example.No need to add calendar.js file. But do include zabuto_calendar.js file. You need to download zabuto_calendar.js this plugin without this you can't proceed further

Comment: I have downloaded the  zabuto_calendar.js file. But, still im getting the error : "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined"

Comment: What about 'holiday.json' file? Should i download it?

Comment: I have already explained, you  need to create holiday.json file which contains json data which will be in this format data=[{ holidayDate": "26-01-2016", "description": "Republic Day", "fullDay": "Y", "HolidayType" : "Public Holiday" }, { "holidayDate": "24-03-2016", "description": "Holi", "fullDay": "Y", "HolidayType" : "Public Holiday" }]